# MVC, JsonResult, DateTime and the Timezone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Good Day my fellow programmers,

I now have spent 2 days looking for a solution, and are about to go crazy..

That's the Problem:

- On The WebPage, the User modifies an object, and i need to store the time *without* timezone info.
  [ i just care about hours and minutes ]
- the object is postet to the Server [ asp.net mvc 5] via ajax as a JsonResult.
- Let's say, Server has Timezone UTC + 1 , User selects 09:00 on the webpage, json is ajax't to my controller, and boom - the resulting Object in my mvc controller has a DateTime Object with a time of 10:00 ;

What i have done: Client-side: Store Time Info in UTC Format  [so a dateobjet.toUTCString() gives me the correct date i want to have, just before postig to the controller]

So is there a way to tell the JsonResult-Converter to just ignore the Timezone-Info and use the UTC-Time?

Thanks,

Mr.Muh

**OK, i hope to describe it in a better (and shorter):**

- ClientSite:  JavaScript date with the time i need in UTC (but still with some timezone information, which i don't need), let's say e.g. 'Fri, 01 Feb 1980 09:00:00 GMT' as a result from .toUTCString()
- Get's wrapped up together with other variables in some Json & posted via ajax to my asp.net mvc 5 controller
- ServerSide: Controller has my C# - Class as Argument (so automatically converting Json-Object to C# - Class), but the resulting DateTime part now says 10:00:00  due to my server TimeZone set to UTC+1.

So, How can i get the correct UTC time stored to my C# DateTime ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You'll need to show some code so we can help. Is the server running Node.Js or another platform?

Comment: It is not entirely clear from your question what you are having trouble with. Perhaps posting some code to show us your controller action and client-side ajax will help. What do you intend to do with this time? Is is just for display or will you be performing calculations?

Comment: I tried to write it in another way.. maybe it's clearer now! Thank you :)

Comment: If you are trying to capture the "Last Updated" type date, why not do this closer to the database and get it out of the client? You could put it in your repo or sproc and have the actual save method add the modified date before saving?

Comment: it's a time information a user should be able to change in browser, otherwise i'd do it completely in serverside code, which would be no problem!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to ignore the timezone.  You can "reset" your `DateTime` object to UTC (without affecting the actual value) using `DateTime.SpecifyKind`:

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(originalDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: This gives me the same DateTime back, as my originalDateTime get's no Timezone Information through the Json-To-C# Converting-Process it seems...:(

Comment: Based on your question edit, why don't you just post the local time to your controller (rather than doing a client-side UTC conversion), and then call DateTime.ToUtcTime() after getting it?  Wouldn't the conversion be implicit at that point?

Comment: I started with that (more or less), which was working fine as long as the server timezone did not changed. As soon it changed, all my saved schedules had the wrong time :/    But maybe i'll try it the other way round, and erase timezone info on loading... i'll give it a try, thanks :)